# Determine change in values in a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Assume a dataset like this (which originally is read in from a .csv):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,1,2,3],
                     'time':['2017-01-01 12:00:00','2017-01-01 12:00:00','2017-01-01 12:00:00',
                          '2017-01-01 12:10:00','2017-01-01 12:10:00','2017-01-01 12:10:00'],
                     'value': [10,11,12,10,12,13]})
```

=>

```
    id  time                    value
0   1   2017-01-01 12:00:00     10
1   2   2017-01-01 12:00:00     11
2   3   2017-01-01 12:00:00     12
3   1   2017-01-01 12:10:00     10
4   2   2017-01-01 12:10:00     12
5   3   2017-01-01 12:10:00     13
```

Time is identical for all IDs in each observation period. The series goes on like that for many observations, i.e. every ten minutes.

I want the number of total changes in the `value` column by id between consecutive times. For example: For id=1 there is no change (result: 0). For id=2 there is one change (result: 1).
Inspired by this post, I have tried taking differences:
[Determining when a column value changes in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196063/determining-when-a-column-value-changes-in-pandas-dataframe)

This is what I've come up so far (not working as expected):

```
data = data.set_index(['id', 'time']) # MultiIndex 
grouped = data.groupby(level='id') 
data['diff'] = grouped['value'].diff()
data.loc[data['diff'].notnull(), 'diff'] = 1
data.loc[data['diff'].isnull(), 'diff'] = 0
grouped['diff'].sum()
```

However, this will just be the sum of occurrences for each id.

Since my dataset is huge (and wont fit into memory), the solution should be as fast as possible. ( This is why I use a MultiIndex on id + time. I expect significant speedup because optimally the data need not be shuffled anymore.)

Moreover, I have come around dask dataframes which are very similar to pandas dfs. A solution making use of them would be fantastic.

Comment: Important: Can one set of readings in one time slot have multiple readings associated with the same ID?

Comment: @COLDSPEED: no, these are observations. For each point in time there is at most one value for each id.

Comment: Well, in that case you have 3 good answers giving you the same thing. Please choose the most helpful solution and accept it.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I did some measuring. Wen and COLDSPEED where very similar. @Vaishali 's first answer is way faster: 
`1 loop, best of 3: 659 ms per loop`
`1 loop, best of 3: 219 ms per loop`

However, I wonder why nobody gave attention to my request for maximal speed. Does the MultiIndex not help with that? Because all your answers won't work with an MultiIndex. Also a solution in dask would be preferable. Especially in combination with MultiIndex this could speed up things.

Comment: The first may be faster but is also incorrect.

Comment: Mind to elaborate? For my case it returns the same output as the other solutions.

Comment: If you have an item that changes from 10 to 11, and then from 11 to 10, the right output will be 2, but `len(set(x)) - 1` will record only 1. This is how you have described your problem statement, and that is how we have interpreted and answered it.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for the explanation. With my actual data   I've done some more timings. There is no significant difference in computing time between using an index or not using one. Also using dask.dataframe there is no speedup (because the apply func cant be reduced).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to evaluate our answers. You mentioned apply, but my answer does not have apply. However if it is the same speed as apply, I guess that's all you've got.

Comment: You could try asking a question in the numba tag and seeing if you'd get any response or speedup. Doubt pandas can do anymore here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
data.groupby('id').value.apply(lambda x: len(set(x)) - 1)
```

You get

```
id
1    0
2    1
3    1
```

Edit: As @COLDSPEED mentioned, if the requirement is to capture change back to a certain value, use

```
data.groupby('id').value.apply(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).sum() - 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for a `groupby` and comparison by `shift`;

```
data.groupby('id')['value'].agg(lambda x: (x != x.shift(-1)).sum() - 1) 

id
1    0
2    1
3    1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @Vaishali I think my answer is the same as yours. I'll just remove it. What do you think?

Comment: Its ok, I personally feel that both are valid answers given within seconds. So as long as no one is copying, its cool:)

Answer (score 3):

```
data.groupby('id').value.agg(lambda x : (x.diff()!=0).sum()).add(-1)
id
1    0
2    1
3    1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Another by using `pct_change`

```
data.groupby('id').value.apply(lambda x : (x.pct_change()!=0).sum()).add(-1)
Out[323]: 
id
1    0
2    1
3    1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Ah I knew there was another method with diff. Was waiting for you to find it +1

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Can not figure it out ,haha ~ waiting for you update ~ :)