# Add a dummy indicating change between consecutive rows in grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

This is a follow up to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288854/determine-change-in-values-in-a-grouped-dataframe).
Assume a dataset like this (which originally is read in from a .csv):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
                     'time':['2017-01-01 12:00:00','2017-01-01 12:00:00','2017-01-01 12:00:00',
                            '2017-01-01 12:10:00','2017-01-01 12:10:00','2017-01-01 12:10:00',
                            '2017-01-01 12:20:00','2017-01-01 12:20:00','2017-01-01 12:20:00'],
                     'values': [10,11,12,10,12,13,10,13,13]})

data = data.set_index('id')
```

=>

```
    id  time                    values
0   1   2017-01-01 12:00:00     10
1   2   2017-01-01 12:00:00     11
2   3   2017-01-01 12:00:00     12
3   1   2017-01-01 12:10:00     10
4   2   2017-01-01 12:10:00     12
5   3   2017-01-01 12:10:00     13
6   1   2017-01-01 12:20:00     10
7   2   2017-01-01 12:20:00     13
8   3   2017-01-01 12:20:00     13
```

Time is identical for all IDs in each observation period. The series goes on like that for many observations, i.e. every ten minutes. 
Previously, I learned how to get the total number of changes in `values` between two consecutive periods for each id:

```
data.groupby(data.index).values.apply(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).sum() - 1)
```

This works great and is really fast. Now, I am interested in adding a new column to the df. It should be a dummy indicating for each row in `values` if there was a change between the current and previous row. Thus, the result would be as follows:

=>

```
    id  time                    values    change
0   1   2017-01-01 12:00:00     10        0
1   2   2017-01-01 12:00:00     11        0
2   3   2017-01-01 12:00:00     12        0
3   1   2017-01-01 12:10:00     10        0
4   2   2017-01-01 12:10:00     12        1
5   3   2017-01-01 12:10:00     13        1
6   1   2017-01-01 12:20:00     10        0
7   2   2017-01-01 12:20:00     13        1
8   3   2017-01-01 12:20:00     13        0
```

After fiddling around, I came up with a solution. However, it is really slow. It won't run on my actual dataset which is rather big:

```
def calc_change(x):
    x = (x != x.shift())
    x.iloc[0,] = False
    return x

changes = data.groupby(data.index, as_index=False).values.apply(
                       calc_change).reset_index().iloc[:,2]
data = data.sort_index().reset_index()
data.loc[changes, 'change'] = 1 
data = data.fillna(0)
```

I'm sure there are better and appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution if your id column is not set as index.

```
data['change'] = data.groupby(['id'])['values'].apply(lambda x: x.diff() > 0).astype(int)
```

You get

```
    id  time             values change
0   1   2017-01-01 12:00:00 10  0
1   2   2017-01-01 12:00:00 11  0
2   3   2017-01-01 12:00:00 12  0
3   1   2017-01-01 12:10:00 10  0
4   2   2017-01-01 12:10:00 12  1
5   3   2017-01-01 12:10:00 13  1
6   1   2017-01-01 12:20:00 10  0
7   2   2017-01-01 12:20:00 13  1
8   3   2017-01-01 12:20:00 13  0
```

With id as index,

```
data = data.sort_index()
data['change'] = data.groupby(data.index)['values'].apply(lambda x: x.diff() > 0).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to get this working with id as an index as well?

Comment: While at first it seemed to work, using this on my actual dataset leads to a seemingly wrong result. If I compare it to `data.groupby('id').values.apply(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).sum() - 1)` the result of `data['change'] = data.groupby(['id'])['values'].apply(lambda x: x.diff() > 0).astype(int)` and then `data.groupby('id').change.sum()` strongly diverges. It is very roughly half in many cases. Any idea? I have about ~1000 ids, Millions of rows and my actual values are latitudes of coords (e.g. 2.12134900 with different lenghts)

Comment: Hmmm, I am sorry but its difficult to do guess work without being able to reproduce the error.

Comment: I was just editing my answer with a minimal example. Thereby, I realized what the problem is.  Your answer will only work if the difference is positive. When a consecutive value is lower than the former, it will not be counted as a change. Here is a correct version: `data.groupby('id')['values'].apply(lambda x: abs(x.diff()) > 0).astype(int)`  Please edit your post so I can accept the answer :)