# Determine if any changes occurred in a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe, similar to this:

```
records = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1001,1001,1001,1002,1002,1002,1003,1003,1003], 
'salary': [500,500,500,300,300,400,100,100,100],
                     'date': ['1/1','4/1','6/1','1/1','4/1','6/1','1/1','4/1','6/1']})
```

Resulting in

```
    id  salary  date
0   1001    500 1/1
1   1001    500 4/1
2   1001    500 6/1
3   1002    300 1/1
4   1002    300 4/1
5   1002    400 6/1
6   1003    100 1/1
7   1003    100 4/1
8   1003    100 6/1
```

There can be more than three entries for each id, it varies.

I want to be able to add a column or otherwise test if, for each id, there was a salary change at some point in the year.

I came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288854/determine-change-in-values-in-a-grouped-dataframe):

```
records.groupby('id').salary.apply(lambda x: len(set(x)) - 1)
```

Unfortunately it did not work for me. In my large dataset, it did find some, but not all, instances where the salary had changed (I knew one ID in particular where there was a salary change, but it did not appear in the results.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use `groupby(...)["column"].nunique()` to get the number of unique elements in a grouped Series:

```
records.groupby('id').salary.nunique()
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try `groupby` id and find out which salary is not equal to the first salary in each group using a lambda function. Allocate best attribute using np.`where`

```
import numpy as np
df['change']=np.where(df.groupby('id').salary.apply(lambda x: x!=x.iloc[0]),'Change','nochange')
print(df)



   id  salary date    change
0  1001     500  1/1  nochange
1  1001     500  4/1  nochange
2  1001     500  6/1  nochange
3  1002     300  1/1  nochange
4  1002     300  4/1  nochange
5  1002     400  6/1    Change
6  1003     100  1/1  nochange
7  1003     100  4/1  nochange
8  1003     100  6/1  nochange
```

Comment: Following up on this answer from a while ago, is there a way to apply this lambda function to the immediately preceding row instead of just the first instance?