# Pandas: Create column which contains 'next' changed value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search

I would like to create column C from column B without a for loop...

dataframe:

```
# |  A  |  B |  C  
--+-----+----+-----
1 |  2  |  3 |  4
2 |  3  |  3 |  4
3 |  4  |  4 |  6
4 |  5  |  4 |  6
5 |  5  |  4 |  6
6 |  3  |  6 |  2
7 |  2  |  6 |  2
8 |  4  |  2 |  3  #< --- loop back around if possible (B value at index 1)
```

Essentially I want to get the value of the next change in B and set it to a new column C.

So far with the answer from : [Determining when a column value changes in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196063/determining-when-a-column-value-changes-in-pandas-dataframe)
I have:

```
df_filtered = df[df['B'].diff() != 0]
```

But after that I'm not sure how to create C without using a loop...

EDIT:
@(Ayoub ZAROU)'s answer answers my original question, however, I noticed my example dataframe doesn't cover all cases if we are assuming a loop in the data:

```
# |  A  |  B |  C  
--+-----+----+-----
1 |  2  |  3 |  4
2 |  3  |  3 |  4
3 |  4  |  4 |  6
4 |  5  |  4 |  6
5 |  5  |  4 |  6
6 |  3  |  6 |  2
7 |  2  |  6 |  2
8 |  4  |  2 |  3
9 |  3  |  3 |  4
10|  2  |  3 |  4
```

In this case, if the last segment of 3's is considered to be part of the first segment of 3's, the last two values in C will be incorrect using this solution.

An easy fix however is to move the last few elements to the beginning of the list or vice versa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try, note that `np.roll` is the same as shift in pandas, the only difference is that it allows you to roll the values over, 
In the following, `c` gives you the indexes where there is no change

```py
c = (df.B.diff(-1) == 0)

c
Out[104]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

we set then the values there to the next value on the `B` column yieldied using [np.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) and set using [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), note that where changes the values where the change column `c` is not `True`,

```py
df['C'] = np.nan
df['C'] = df.C.where(c, np.roll(df.B, -1))
df.C

Out[107]: 
0    NaN
1    4.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    6.0
5    NaN
6    2.0
7    3.0
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

we then fill the remaining rows using `bfill` on pandas and cast it it the `B` ' column `dtype`, 
So , in global, you do

```py
c = (df.B.diff(-1) == 0)
df['C'] = np.nan
df['C'] = df.C.where(c, np.roll(df.B, -1)).bfill().astype(df.B.dtype)
```

```py
df.C
Out[110]: 
0    4
1    4
2    6
3    6
4    6
5    2
6    2
7    3
Name: C, dtype: int32
```

Comment: bfill() is definitely what I was looking for, I'm guessing you meant df.B.shift(-1) instead of A?
I guess I after that I could set NaN values to the first value in B

Comment: I just edited my answer to include that, yeah and I confused `B` with `A`

Comment: This definitely works, but I'm having trouble understanding how. could you explain a bit how the last step works?

Comment: also this creates a float, so have to cast to int at some point

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to get the value changes:

```
In [11]: changes = (df.B != df.B.shift()).cumsum()

In [12]: changes
Out[12]:
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    4
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

and a lookup map:

```
In [13]: lookup = df.B[(df.B != df.B.shift())]

In [14]: lookup.at[len(lookup)] = df.B.iloc[0]

In [15]: lookup
Out[15]:
0    3
2    4
5    6
7    2
4    3
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Then use these to lookup the "next":

```
In [16]: lookup.iloc[changes]
Out[16]:
2    4
2    4
5    6
5    6
5    6
7    2
7    2
4    3
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

To create the column you need to ignore the duplicates in the index:

```
In [17]: df["C"] = lookup.iloc[changes].values
```

Comment: That said, Ayoub's is a much more efficient way to do this!

Comment: whoa that's brilliant though, this logic definitely will be helpful with other problems I think

Comment: Long time no see Andy!... this does have the advantage that it'll work with "groups" in general and not just numerics... I was thinking along the same lines...

Comment: @JonClements Cabbage Jon! Hope you've been keeping yourself busy :)

Answer (score 1):

shift `B`,  groupby on original `df.B`. Finally, `transform` and `fillna`

```
df.B.shift(-1).groupby([df.B]).transform('last').fillna(df.at[1,'B'])

Out[22]:
1    4.0
2    4.0
3    6.0
4    6.0
5    6.0
6    2.0
7    2.0
8    3.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

---

You may also use `np.roll` with `assign` to create a column `C` and groupby `B` and `transform` on `C`. Doing this way, you don't need `shift` and `fillna`

```
df.assign(C=np.roll(df.B,-1)).groupby('B').C.transform('last')

Out[36]:
1    4
2    4
3    6
4    6
5    6
6    2
7    2
8    3
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).
Let's do it with an example. Consider a Dataframe:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'], data=[[1,2], [5,6], [5,3]])
print(a)

Out[0]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  5  6
2  5  3
```

Then use shift to create a column 'c'

```
a['c'] = a.b.shift(1)
Out[1]: 
   a  b    c
0  1  2  NaN
1  5  6  2.0
2  5  3  6.0
```

Then deduct column 'b' with column 'c'.

```
a.c = a.b - a.c
Out[2]: 
   a  b    c
0  1  2  NaN
1  5  6  4.0
2  5  3 -3.0
```

This gives you the next changed value, difference between column 'b' and 'c'.
Hope it helps.