# Python Dataframe produce binary output when the value in a column changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I came across this answer [Determining when a column value changes in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196063/determining-when-a-column-value-changes-in-pandas-dataframe) about finding when the value in a data frame changes. I have a similar problem but want to produce a binary output.

My code:

```
df = 
      A
0    10 
1    20
2    20
3    50
4    50
5    30


df['B'] =  df['A'].diff()

df = 
      A    B
0    10    Nan 
1    20    10
2    20    0
3    50    30
4    50    0
5    30    -20
```

I am expecting output something like this

```
df = 
      A    B     C
0    10    Nan   1 
1    20    10    1
2    20    0     0
3    50    30    1
4    50    0     0
5    30    -20   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an additional step to check if `B` equals `0`:

```
df['B'] = df.A.diff()
df['C'] = df.B.ne(0).view('i1')

print(df)

    A     B  C
0  10   NaN  1
1  20  10.0  1
2  20   0.0  0
3  50  30.0  1
4  50   0.0  0
5  30 -20.0  1
```

---

Not recommending, but since you've asked, we can make it a one liner with `eval`:

```
df['B'], df['C'] = df.assign(B=df.A.diff()).eval('B, B!=0')
```

Comment: Can we do it in one line? Also, what is the meaning `.view('i1')`in your code?

Comment: I just tried this `.diff().ne(0)`. it is working. THis is fine for me.

Comment: Added a one liner, though I'd go with the first, for readability purposes. `view` will *view* the boolean result as an integer @Mainland